# Operator= not working C++

Tags: c++

I have this in my code:

```
const Member & Member::operator=( const Member & rhs )
{
    strcpy(  this->firstName, rhs.firstName ); 
    strcpy( this->lastName ,  rhs.lastName );
    this->gender = rhs.gender;
    this->year = rhs.year;
    return *this;
}
```

and for some reason it doesn't work if I use it.

It tells me that can't convert `Member` to `Member&`
my teacher has it in a different class the same way and his works. I don't get why I think the signature is right and so is the return value. Some explanation could help. Thank you

```
Member found;

found = vertices[0].find(set.familyHead); //returns a member
```

ERROR:

```
C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\p4-2>make
g++ -ansi -Wno-reorder -Wall -g -c familyRunner.cpp
g++ -ansi -Wno-reorder -Wall -g -c familytree.cpp
familytree.cpp: In member function 'void FamilyTree::findSet(FamilySet&)':
familytree.cpp:26:8: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Member'
 and 'Member')
  found = vertices[0].find(set.familyHead);
        ^
familytree.cpp:26:8: note: candidate is:
In file included from familytree.h:6:0,
                 from familytree.cpp:1:
Member.h:19:17: note: const Member& Member::operator=(Member&)
  const Member & operator=(  Member & rhs );
                 ^
Member.h:19:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Member' to 'Member&'
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'familytree.o' failed
make: *** [familytree.o] Error 1
```

teacher's signature:

```
const string & operator= ( const string & rhs );  // Copy
```

Comment: Show us code where you perform assignment of Member objects.

Comment: Also, `operator=` is usually defined as taking a `const` reference, since it should never modify `rhs`.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need `this->` in C++, except under certain circumstances when templates are involved. (But it is sometimes good to write `this->` for clarity, anyway.)

Comment: Show the `class` declaration. BTW, you should use `std::string`

Comment: Almost certainly, you *don't* have it the same way your teacher has it.

Comment: You're learning about assignment operators, but not learning to use `std::string`?

Comment: am I mixing up the difference between copy and assignment? Could someone please explain or show the differences between the two's signatures

Comment: can't use string. I'll post an example and my teacher's code

Comment: The usual signature would be `Member& Member::operator=(const Member & rhs )`. Still, there is not enough information to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `can't use string.`  Man, this `std::string` has some sort of contagious disease or something.  Why so many say "can't use std::string?"  And in your case, especially now that you're learning what copy and assignment are, it requires that you make your copies with no chance of error.

Comment: its cause he built his own string class we use. But here he told us that strcpy would be better to work with. also I forgot const when I was just playing with the code

Comment: @csCarngie So why don't you use this string class?  `But here he told us that strcpy would be better to work with`???? Your teacher has no confidence in their own coding??  If the string class they coded is safe, then use it.  It is much better than calling raw `strcpy`, where you have no control if a string buffer does not have enough room.

Comment: I don't know. I'm just following instructions I already asked if I could use it. He prolly doesn't. But I do need to know why I can't assign something to member.

Comment: @csCarngie You are returning a const object.  How is `found` declared?  As to your teacher, I would crash the app on purpose and show them why *not* using their string class causes problems.

Comment: Yeah I am not a fan of the school or how CS is generally taught either. I think this assignment doesn't really teach much concept more than annoyance. Cause I’m just showing you a small part of what the whole program is.

Comment: I did some research and forgot about the big 3 and read up on that and got it done. So thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely you're trying to use an rvalue, something like the following:

```
A a;
a = A();
```

If this is the case, the temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference. Hence, the error. You can use the more conventional signature for a copy assignment operator where the parameter is `const A&`. Another thing you might want to do is changed your return type to `A&`, to allow operator chaining. For example:

```
A a;
A b;
A c;
a = b = c;
```

Finally, I recommend you check out our homebrew FAQ question, [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

---

The FAQ goes into detail, but currently your copy assignment operator does not account for two major problems:

- Self-assignment
- And if the source string is larger than the destination string

Ideally, you should just follow the [Rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and use a `std::string` data member. Your class will automagically do the right thing if you *don't* labor over manually implementing special member functions.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i did some research on the Big 3 and forgot that if you declare one you have to declare them all. Thanks this was a big help.